# Why is the task status in DolphinScheduler always in the successfully submitted status?

Tags: bigdata, workflow, scheduler, data-pipeline

when I click the `Start` button to run the workflow, I meet the following situation: the task status always in the successfully submitted status, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1、first check whether the WorkerServer service exists through jps, or directly check whether there is a worker service in zk from the service monitoring.

2、If the WorkerServer service is normal, you need to check whether the MasterServer puts the task task in the zk queue. You need to check whether the task is blocked in the MasterServer log and the zk queue.

3、If there is no problem above, you need to locate whether the Worker group is specified, but the machine grouped by the worker is not online.